# Debug springboot application by running .sh file using IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a springboot application that has a local.sh file which contains some exports and mvn path, application jar paths. To run the application, i run this command in terminal './local.sh' (I use Mac).

I want to run my application in debug mode.

Tried with this approach, but application still running in run mode.

Added new Shell script configuration, gave the script path and in Script options entered 'set -x', gave the working directory. After this configuration, clicked on debug icon.

Is there any other way that i can run springboot application in debug mode by running .sh file?

Please let me know if you need more information.